# Segmentation fault, initializing recursive struct in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

Okay, I put together a simplified example of the problem code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

struct Trie{
    //Holds sub-tries for letters a-z
    struct Trie *sub[26];
    //Is this a substring, or a complete word?
    int is_word;
};
typedef struct Trie Trie;

Trie dictionary;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //A list of words
    char *words[7] = {"the","of","and","to","a","in","that"};

    //Add the words to the Trie structure
    int i=0, wordlen;
    Trie *sub_dict;
    for (;i<7; i++){
        //Reset
        printf("NEW WORD\n");
        sub_dict = &dictionary;
        //Add a word to the dictionary
        int j=0, c;
        while (c = words[i][j], c != '\0'){
            printf("char = %c\n",c);
            //Initialize the sub-Trie
            if (sub_dict->sub[c-97] == NULL)
                sub_dict->sub[c-97] = (Trie*) malloc(sizeof(Trie*));
            //Set as new sub-trie
            sub_dict = sub_dict->sub[c-97];
            j++;
        }
        sub_dict->is_word = 1;
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a Trie data structure that holds the letters "a" through "z". I have a list of words that should get added inside the `while` loop. Unfortunately, I get a segmentation fault at different points in the loop (depending on when I run it).

I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the line
`sub_dict->sub[c-97] = (Trie*) malloc(sizeof(Trie*));`
but I'm new to `C`, so I have absolutely no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sub_dict->sub[c-97] = (Trie*) malloc(sizeof(Trie*));`
there is an error.

`sizeof(Trie*)` will be 4 in 32bit os, because `Trie*` is a pointer, and the size of a pointer in 32bit os is 4.
you can do like this: `sub_dict->sub[c-97] = (Trie*) malloc(sizeof(Trie));`

Comment: Why does it segfault if I do `Trie temp; sub_dict->sub[c-97] = &temp;` instead? Shouldn't that do the same thing as using `malloc`?

Comment: Because you go writing beyond the end of the memory that was allocated, so you trampled over `malloc()`'s control information, so it got confused about which memory it should give you next.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to presume that when you do

```
something = (Trie*) malloc(sizeof(Trie*));
```

then the contents of that structure is initialized to zeroes (e.g. every member will start as NULL). This is not the case with [malloc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc). You have to either use [calloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc), or use [memset()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) to reset it after allocation.

In fact, I'd call memset even on your starting dictionary to be on the safe side. (Even though global and static variables [are apparently initialized to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091499/7806), so this might not be necessary for your case.)

Comment: So, will the structure just be filled with a bunch of garbage then? Is it only by luck that `sub_dict->sub[c-97] == NULL` gives the intended result?

Comment: Yes; use `calloc()` to get zeroed memory.  The data returned by `malloc()` may contain any sort of garbage; it is at most accidentally zeroed.