# diffculty in entering strings in C using pointer

Tags: c

The following program works in gcc but on giving the value of T = 6, this program continues and does not end on asking for input strings. Any help guys if you recognise whats wrong with this program?

```
int main()
{ int T,i,j;
  char *strings[T];
  printf("Enter the Number of Strings to Reverse : \n");

  scanf("%d ",&T);

  for(i=0;i<T;i++)
   { strings[i] = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
     scanf("%s\n",strings[i]);
   }
  for(i=0;i<T;i++)
   {printf(" The String %d is : %s\n",i+1,strings[i]);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `T` is uninitialized  when you are creating your pointer array `strings`

Comment: @Andreas got it, but the array is 0 length (T would be initialized to 0), right?

Comment: @Andreas T will be given by the user when program executes.

Comment: But then `strings` is already allocated. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049777/why-global-variables-are-always-initialized-to-0-but-not-local-variables

Comment: @user1463736 but at that moment `strings` will be initialized already with `0`

Comment: @JohnYost local variables cannot be counted on to be initialized implicitly, so no, T would not (reliably) be initialized to 0.

Comment: Ah! Got it. Didn't consider the scope.

Comment: @Dabo if i input the value of T as 1 or 2 or 3 till 5 answer comes but whats wrong with it with T = 6. Please run it once on gcc and let me know the error

Comment: @Andreas if i input the value of T as 1 or 2 or 3 till 5 answer comes but whats wrong with it with T = 6. Please run it once on gcc and let me know the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is not initialized inside `main()` therefore has an undefined value.

`char *strings[T]` creates an array of `char *` pointers of an undefined length.

Fix this using:

```
int T=6;
```

Or, given `T` is in fact constant:

```
const int T=6
```

or perhaps better

```
#define T 6
```

Feel free to use a more mnemonic name than T.

Comment: but T value will be given by user when program executes.

Comment: @user1463736, yes, but then the array of pointers is **already allocated** in memory!

Comment: @smarinov ok got it now. Thanks everyone for the help !

Comment: You could move the declaration of `strings` after `T` has been read. However, you are relying on (I believe) a gnu extension for that to work. A more common way would be to dynamically allocate a data structure of size `T * sizeof (char *)` using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

T is not initialised  (Remember in C++, local scope variables are not automatically initialised) :

```
int T= 6;
```