# C's weird pointer arithmetics 2

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Again I have a very stupid question, I just can't find an answer to. This time I want to know, why the member method works. Especially the `while` loop in the member method. So why does the following code work:

```
while(current){
  if(current->i==a){
  return 1;
  }
  ...
}
```

Why does the argument `while(current)` not produce a infinite execution?

This is the whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct liste{
  int i;
  struct liste *next;
};

struct liste *m [4];
struct liste *current;

int hash(int b){
  printf("%i\n",sizeof(m));
  return b%sizeof(m);
}

int insert(int a){
  struct liste *new = malloc(sizeof(struct liste));
  if(new){
    new->i = a;
    new->next=m[hash(a)];
    m[hash(a)] = new;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int member(int a){
  current = m[hash(a)];
  while(current){
    if(current->i==a){
      return 1;
    }
    current = current->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 1st snippet won't even compile.

Comment: You perhaps want to switch to a more sane indention scheme ...?

Comment: OT: Appliying the `sizeof` operator evaluates to `size_t`, which is `unsigned`, so using the `i` conversion specifier is wrong in any case. In a POSIX environment us `zu`, under windows use `u` (32bit) or `lu` (64bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code snippet doesn't cover all of the loop:

```
 while(current) {
   if(current->i==a) {
     return 1;
   }   
   current = current->next; // Important!
 } // this is the end of the loop's body
```

The last statement inside the loop changes the value of `current`. Eventually it'll be `NULL`, which is when the loop terminates.

---

Seems your question is more about why this

```
// ...
current = m[hash(a)];
while(current){
// ...
```

works even though the elements of `m` weren't explicitly initialised to NULL. As pointed out in the comments of the other answer the reason is that globals are - in contrast to local variables - default initialised.

I'd would like to add that IMHO the code in its current form isn't well written. Since this is effectively a hash table, this should be packed into functions operating on some `struct hashtable` instead of some global variables.

Answer (score 4):

You have to consider the complete `while` loop:

```
while(current){
    if(current->i==a){
        return 1;
    }   
    current = current->next;
}
```

As long as the condition of the `if` is false, `current` is modified in each cycle of the `while` loop.

Also, in case `a` is not in the list, `current` will become `NULL` (or 0) after the whole list was searched. Then the `while` loop will terminate, because its condition is evaluated to `false`.

Note: In your program, the array `m` is a global variable. [Global variables are always initialized to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14049777/2675154). The initial value of an array element is copied to the `next` pointer in the `insert()` function in the following line:

```
new->next=m[hash(a)];
```

Therefore, the final `next` in the list will always be 0.

Comment: But why does current become 'Null', the array m contains struct pointers. Those contain per default a random address.

Comment: I can't see it from the code that you posted, but I assumed that the `next` pointer of a `list` element is initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: No they aren't and that's the hook. Thats why I don't understand why this code works.

Comment: IMHO, if the 4 elements of `m` are not set to `NULL` or 0, for example, in your `main()` function, then the code shouln't work reliably. This is, because the initial value of an array element is copied to the `next` pointer in the `insert()` function.

Comment: That's correct. It shouldn't work, but it works. By the way, this is not my code, but the code of a friend of mine and I can't understand why this works even on my machine with an up to date gcc.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. The array `m` is a global variable. [Global variables are always initialized to 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14049777/2675154).