# why doesn´t char newWord[45]; have "clean" values at the start of a function like char newWord[45] = ""; does?

Tags: c, cs50

I´m a bit confused with these 2.

I have a function called check that does the following:

```
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char newWord[LENGTH + 1] = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++)
    {
        newWord[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
}
```

Now for example if I use `=""`, the variable `newWord` will have all of it´s values as `'\0'` anytime I run the function `check();`

But when using `char newWord[LENGTH + 1];` the variable seems to keep the old values even after my functions has returned, so when I do `check()` again, the `char newWord` already has values from the previous time I ran that function.

I know this is related to pointers and memory allocation but I just cannot seem to get how this works.

Comment: No, this is not related to pointers at all. It is purely about initialization of non-static variables. Only variables with static lifetime are initialized. Other variables are not initialized at all. It does not matter whether it is a pointer, an array, an integer or any other data type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are global variables always initialized to '0', but not local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049777/why-are-global-variables-always-initialized-to-0-but-not-local-variables)

Comment: thanks guys im going to dive into this. i think i understand a bit better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a fancy answer, but compilers (and *versions* of compilers) have different opinions on whether to initialize memory before you use it.  Unless things have changed recently, the only variables that get automatically initialized are variables with a static scope (global variables and those explicitly marked `static`).

For everything else, certain compilers *might* set everything to zeroes (or another value for debugging), but most won't add that small overhead to your program, when you're probably just going to assign a value of your own, soon enough.  One of the biggest debugging effort of my career was because we changed C compilers from one that didn't pre-initialize variables (like most do) to one that did, exposing a bunch of errors my predecessors didn't catch (assigning to the wrong variable, looking for non-zero values and suddenly finding them), so it's an important feature to know about.

The key to your question, though is "*seems* to keep," because it's only an accident that the old string is still in the right position.  If you call another function between `check()` calls, you'll start to see different scratch memory.

Moral of the story?  Always initialize every one of your variables, unless you absolutely know that it's going to get a value before you use it.

Comment: Thank you i think i understand it now. Makes total sense, if you don´t have a value for that variable yet, initialize it to an empty string or 0 to avoid garbage values.

Comment: Static is a storage duration, not a scope. Storage duration is when during program execution an object exists. Scope is where in source code an identifier is visible.

Comment: How would I initialize an array of structs then? because i cant seem to assign it to null:

node *table[N];
node *table[N] = NULL; //doesnt work

Comment: @NunoCarro, your best bet is going to be [`memset()`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/string.h/memset), because there's (unfortunately) no direct answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, it depends on who you are. From the perspective of writing a compiler that implements the C compiler, you're 100% right. From the perspective of more general programming language design, storage duration *is* just C's jargon for what everybody else calls scope.

Comment: @JohnC: No, it does not depend on who you are. The terms are formally defined in the C standard, and both general C programs and compiler implementors should understand them. They have different effects, properties, and consequences. Using the terms incorrectly causes confusion that has to be corrected eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The values that you find after running `check()` twice are **still** garbage values. When you allocate some memory using

```c
char newWord[LENGTH + 1];
```

You are always getting "some" memory that the operating system handles you (in laymen-terms), having initially garbage values. It is just a coincidence that you're getting the same memory blocks that you got from the previous call to `check()`.
However, when you do:

```c
char newWord[LENGTH + 1] = "";
```

You are **explicitly** initializing those memory blocks to `\0`.

Comment: Would you consider then the second way of initializing my array the best proccedure, if i dont have a value ahead of time, i should initialize to an empty string? 

What you are saying makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is a good practice to always initialize any variable or a block of memory you allocate. Because this will prevent you from going into "it works on my machine" things, where you have a working code simply because the garbage values (like this example) were initialized to something that made your code work :/ so, yes, always initialize your variables :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't initialize a local variable, it has an *indeterminate value*. Which could be anything, including random "garbage" or left-overs sitting in RAM memory since previous execution. There are no guarantees of what value you will get - and that's it.

Accessing such an uninitialized variable's value might also invoke undefined behavior in some cases:
[(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior)