# How do I declare a pointer with a constant variable

Tags: c, pointers, integer

Below is my code:
When I run it, I get the following statements:

```
X is equal to 1 and k is equal to 1 
X is equal to 0 and k is equal to 0
```

What I wish to achieve is to have both statements stating the same thing (equal to 1). I understand I can just set the integers x, and k respectively to 1 underneath the if statement, however I want to know how to store a value after the function is executed, so that x and k remain equal to one after execution of the second function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void run_times( int runs);

int main (){
    int i;

    while ( i <3) {
        run_times(i);
        printf("Looped\n");
        i++;
    }
}

void run_times( int runs) {
    int *x,k;

    if (runs == 0) {
        x = &k;
        *x = 1;
        printf("X is equal to %d and k is equal to%d\n", *x, k);
    }   
    if (runs == 1){
        printf("X is equal to %d and k is equal to%d\n", *x, k);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
void run_times( int runs) {
    static int *x,k;
```

A `static` variable means that variable keeps its values between invocations.

Note that the code as asked is running with uninitialized local variables, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So it may or may not work anyway, IDE one runs as you want it to without any changes! http://ideone.com/X7dqHr

Note that we do not have that problem with `static` variables as they are initialized to zero. See: [Why are global and static variables initialized to their default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091499/why-global-and-static-variables-are-initialized-to-their-default-values)

Comment: Thank you, I wish I had known it was that simple haha

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by making `k` `static` (there is really no need for the pointer in this case). The result will be similar to global variable - which are generally a bad idea. Usually it makes more sense to make the declaration local:

```
void run_times(int *x, int runs) {
    printf("x is equal to %d\n", *x);
    if (runs == 0) {
        *x = 1;
    }   
}
```

This way it will still work, if you ever decide you need two separate states:

```
int main() {
    int k0 = 0;
    int k1 = 2;
    int i = 0;
    while ( i <3) {
        run_times(&k0, i);
        run_times(&k1, i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

It should be also clearer to the reader, as you are not passing data via hidden variables.