# Creating a hollow rectangle without adding spaces as its elements in C

Tags: c, if-statement, multidimensional-array, stdio

The following code creates a hollow rectangle with 2D-Array.

```
int main(){
int x,y;
    for(x=0; x<11; x++)
        for(y=0; y<11; y++)
            if (x==0 || x==10 || y==0 || y==10)
                box [x][y] = '=';
            else{
                box[x][y]=' ';
            }
}
```

The `if` functions creates the border and the `else` functions creates the hollow space within it.

Is it possible to do this without the letting `else` add blanks into my array?

Simply getting rid of the `else` condition fills the supposedly empty spaces full of weird characters.

Comment: Well you *could* initialize the matrix with all spaces to begin with. But besides that, how else would you create the "hollow ***space***"? Also, why don't you want the `else` clause? What's wrong with it?

Comment: You could initialize to all spaces with `memset`. Then just fill in the borders.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm running this in a loop and everytime the loop repeats the content within turns into spaces again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Simply getting rid of the else condition fills the supposedly empty spaces full of weird characters.

Since `box` appears to be a global variable, its content is initially initialized to all zeros ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091499/335858))

You want the content to be initialized to spaces, so you need to do one of the following:

- Write a loop to pre-fill `box[][]` with spaces, or
- Use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) to pre-fill `box[][]` with spaces, or
- Keep the `else` branch, which fills unused `box[][]` cells with spaces.

I would prefer the last solution as the most economical. I would also rewrite the loop with a conditional expression, like this:

```
for(y=0; y<11; y++) {
    box [x][y] = (x==0 || x==10 || y==0 || y==10) ? '=' : ' ';
}
```

Comment: The reason I don't want to use the `else` statement is that this function runs within a `do`...`while` loop and every time I update the content of the array and the loop repeats, this functions clears the content.

Comment: @Raph The use one of two other approaches (e.g. call `memset(box, ' ', sizeof(box))` before your loop).