# Unexpected failed test case for codeforces 455A boredom

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

Guys I am new to competitive programming I was solving a problem([455A BOREDOM](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/455/A)) ,I took a solution and tried it to understand it. I believe I understand that that well but I have a small doubt.

```
   #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    #define MAX 100005
    long long dp[100005];
        long long count1[100005];
        int main(){
        int n,x;
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin >> x;
            count1[x]++;
           // res=max(res,x);
        }
        dp[0]=0;
        dp[1]=count1[1];
        for(int i=2;i<MAX;i++){
            dp[i]=max(dp[i-1],dp[i-2]+i*count1[i]);
        }
        cout<<dp[MAX-1];
    }
```

However as you can see that the loop is running MAX(100005) even for small test cases. When I tried to optimize that I came up with the following solution:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long dp[100005];
    long long count1[100005];
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int x;
    int res=-100000;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> x;
        count1[x]++;
        res=max(res,x);
    }

    dp[0]=0;
    dp[1]=count1[1];

    for(int i=2;i<=res;i++){
        dp[i]=max(dp[i-1],dp[i-2]+i*count1[i]);
    }

    cout<< dp[res];


}
```

However this is giving me the wrong answer on test case 12 https://codeforces.com/contest/455/submission/47841668

The site reported the following error on test case 12:

> runtime error: signed integer overflow: 98997 * 8608623459288743937 cannot be represented in type 'long long'

on this line `dp[i]=max(dp[i-1],dp[i-2]+i*count1[i]);`

Can anyone tell me where i did the mistake ?
Why that competitive programmer that kind of mistake is that normal?

Comment: Competitive programming is a load of nonsense. Instead, get yourself a good book on C++ and learn how to solve real-world problems with real-world code.

Comment: You probably should have included the diagnostics for the failure and the test case. The site tells you what the problem is ***runtime error: signed integer overflow: 98997 * 8608623459288743937 cannot be represented in type 'long long'*** on this line `dp[i]=max(dp[i-1],dp[i-2]+i*count1[i]);`

Comment: Note that when you moved your variables to the local scope inside main() they are no longer initialized to 0 that they were as global variables. So count is full of garbage data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that now that you moved `long long count1[100005];` to be inside `int main()` it is no longer default initialized to `0` as it would when it was a global variable.

[Why are global and static variables initialized to their default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091499/why-are-global-and-static-variables-initialized-to-their-default-values)

So when you do this

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin >> x;
    count1[x]++;
    res=max(res,x);
}
```

count1[x] has random garbage values that you increment and then use in the calculation here: `dp[i]=max(dp[i-1],dp[i-2]+i*count1[i])` which caused your runtime error reported by the site:

> runtime error: signed integer overflow: 98997 * 8608623459288743937 cannot be represented in type 'long long' on this line dp[i]=max(dp[i-1],dp[i-2]+i*count1[i]);

You can see that count1[i] in this case is `8608623459288743937`

To fix this you can replace `long long count1[100005];` with `long long count1[100005]= {};`

[How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value)

Note: That `dp` is also not automatically initialized to 0. However it is not a problem since you don't read uninitialized values of `dp` like you did with `count1`. `dp[i-1]` and `dp[i-2]` have been initialized when you use them here `dp[i]=max(dp[i-1],dp[i-2]+i*count1[i]);`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR WRITING SUCH A HELPFUL ANSWER

Comment: @akash12121 Please, stop SHOUTING at everybody!