# How to have a global variable in C that increments when used by any function

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables

I am attempting to have a gobal counter the can can used by any function in the program. Is this possible?

```
int* count;

main(){
   *count = 0;
}

void incrementCount(){
   ++*count;
}

int getCount(){
   return *count;
}
```

If not possible how can I do something similar?

Comment: regarding: `int* count;`  this declares a pointer to `int`   However, that pointer is never actually pointer to memory that the application owns,  Given where it is declared, it will contain NULL.   Any effort to modify a value at address 0 (NULL) will result in a seg fault event

Answer (score 2):

No need to take a pointer. Take a Variable like

`int count;`

If you are going to use it in a single file better to declare it `static`.

A much better approach would be using the getter and setter functions instead of updating global variable everywhere

Answer (score 1):

> I am attempting to have a gobal counter the can can used by any function in the program. Is this possible?

Yes, even though it's not a good thing to use global variable.

All you need to do is to declare the function in global scope. You should also initialise it in `main` before any function call.

```
int count;

int main()
{
    count = 0;
    incrementCount();
    ...
}
```

There is no need to use pointer in your case. And it's wrong as well, because you have not allocate any memory for that pointer.

Comment: Not strictly necessary to explicitly init as globals are always automatically initialised to 0.

Comment: @kaylum - that's true. Anyway explicit initialisation is still better, as not all types have implicit initialisation.

Comment: Are you thinking of C++? AFAIK, in C all globals without an initialiser are implicitly initialised to 0. That's because they are part of the BSS which is always loaded into zeroed memory. It's not a big point but just wanted to clarify that in case it causes any misunderstanding for future readers.

Comment: @kaylum - you're right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091499/why-are-global-and-static-variables-initialized-to-their-default-values

Anyway I think explicit initialisation won't harm, and perhaps a good habit too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are few issues in the shared code sample. Here

```
int* count; /* count is pointer i.e you need to make count to hold or point to some valid memory location */
```

`count` is of *int pointer* type. And here

```
 *count = 0; /* de-referencing uninitiated pointer */
```

you are trying to de-reference `count` which has not valid memory. It causes segmentation fault. Before de-referencing you need to allocate memory. for e.g

```
 count = malloc(sizeof(*count));
 /* error handling of malloc return value */
 *count = 0;
```

> I am attempting to have a gobal counter the can can used by any
>   function in the program ?

You can do the same task without using pointer, try using `static` if use having file scope. If possible avoid using global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare the variable as *integer* (not pointer).
You can have a global `getter` and `setter` function. Also initialize the global variable before any function call, best will be in `Main()`.

Answer (score 0):

> first, you can't do

```
*count = 0;
```

> if you don't have initialised your pointer, it means refrenced to a
>   variable like:

```
count = &x;
```

> Then, if you want that variable is shared and the value is always
>   updated between methods you can simply declare the variable as
>   "static",

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int count;

    main(){
       printf("%d",count);
    }

    void incrementCount(){
       ++count;
    }

    int getCount(){
       return count;
    }
```

Comment: the OPs posted code is tagged as C, not C++  So the statement: `cout` will cause a failure of the code to compile as the function: `cout` is not part of the c language