# 2D dimensional array (C)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Hi im new at stackoverflow and also beginner into c and trying to solve this
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuXzD.png)
My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int sales[5][4];
    int salesPersons, products=0;
    int value=0;

    printf("Enter salesperon number: ");
    scanf("%d", &salesPersons);
    
    while(salesPersons != 0){
        printf("Enter product number: ");
        scanf("%d", &products);
        printf("Enter value: ");
        scanf("%d", &value);

        if(salesPersons >= 1 && products >= 1 && products < 6 && value >= 0)
            sales[products - 1][salesPersons - 1] += value;
        else
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
        printf("Enter salesperson number (Enter 0 to exit inputting): ");
        scanf("%d", &salesPersons);
    }

    printf("%7s%7s%7s%7s%7s%7s%7s\n", "N", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "TOTAL");
    int totalProduct[5] = {0}, totalPerson[4] = {0};
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        printf("%7d", row + 1);
            for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
                printf("%7d", sales[row][column]);
                totalProduct[row] += sales[row][column];
                totalPerson[column] += sales[row][column];
        }
        printf("%7d\n", totalProduct[row]);
    }
    printf("%7s%7d%7d%7d%7d%7d\n", "TOTAL", totalPerson[0],totalPerson[1],totalPerson[2],totalPerson[3],totalPerson[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

I tested with only 1 salesperson, product, and value. But turns out the output printing number it shouldnt printed. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
Enter salesperon number: 1
Enter product number: 2
Enter value: 3
Enter salesperson number (Enter 0 to exit inputting): 0
      N     P1     P2     P3     P4     P5  TOTAL 
      11928634432  2208215775231      0    1971944432139
      2    197      0-1490587977  32766-14905879781313824304
      3-1490587978  327661928639853  22082-34104450497062219
      4-341044504  327421928639776  22082      01587650096
      5      0      01928638656  22082-1490587712438073026
  TOTAL97002147  8759016138243  99012-1377788055
```

Comment: `int sales[5][4];` ==> `int sales[5][4] = {{0}};` The expression `sales[products - 1][salesPersons - 1] += value;` invokes *undefined behavior* when the content of `sales[products - 1][salesPersons - 1]` is indeterminate (which yours is, as it was declared and defined, but never given any initial state).

Comment: @WhozCraig: `sales[products - 1][salesPersons - 1] += value;` does not have undefined behavior due to `sales[products - 1][salesPersons - 1]` having an indeterminate value. Having an indeterminate value simply means some unspecified value is used. That is not undefined behavior; “undefined behavior” means nothing about the behavior is specified by the C standard. But, in this case, the standard specifies part of the behavior, which is that an unpsecified value is used, and the computation otherwise proceeds as usual.

Comment: @WhozCraig, `int sales[5][4] = {0}` works as well

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments section, variables are not being initialized.
They would be automatically initialized to zero if they were `global` or `static` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091499/why-are-global-and-static-variables-initialized-to-their-default-values)). You can initialized them in the same way you did for `totalPerson`, that is, `totalPerson[4] = {0};`. Note this is the same as `totalPerson[4] = {0,};`, only the first element is initialized explicitly. When any element of the array is explicitly initialized, all other elements are zero initialized by default (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value)). So doing `totalPerson[4] = {1};` would initialize it to `[1, 0, 0, 0]`. Some people prefer the `totalPerson[4] = {1,};` notation because of this.

Apart from initialization, there's still another issue: you are allocating only `4` bytes for arrays in which you are trying to use `5` bytes. As arrays are [zero-indexed in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320686/why-does-the-indexing-start-with-zero-in-c), accesses such as the following:

```
totalPerson[column] += sales[row][column];
```

Will cause error when `column` is `4`, since indexing with `4` is access to the 5th element of the array, and both `totalPerson` and `sales` have only `4` bytes allocated in that dimension.

So change the following line:

```
int sales[5][4];
```

With:

```
int sales[5][5] = {0};
```

And:

```
int totalProduct[5] = {0}, totalPerson[4] = {0};
```

With:

```
int totalProduct[5] = {0}, totalPerson[5] = {0};
```

So the program will work as expected:

```
$ ./program 
Enter salesperon number: 1
Enter product number: 1
Enter value: 10
Enter salesperson number (Enter 0 to exit inputting): 2
Enter product number: 1
Enter value: 20
Enter salesperson number (Enter 0 to exit inputting): 1
Enter product number: 5
Enter value: 50
Enter salesperson number (Enter 0 to exit inputting): 0
      N     P1     P2     P3     P4     P5  TOTAL
      1     10     20      0      0      0     30  
      2      0      0      0      0      0      0   
      3      0      0      0      0      0      0   
      4      0      0      0      0      0      0   
      5     50      0      0      0      0     50  
  TOTAL     60     20      0      0      0
```